# Adobe Echosign SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field

Tags: soql, api, custom-object

I added Adobe Echosign for Salesforce, but keep getting the following error:

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
>   field: echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c.echosign_dev1__Account__r.

What I did:

I created a template, with servicecontract (a custom object) as master object type. Added a send for signature button on the service contract, with code:

```
/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess?masterid={!ServiceContract.Id}&templateId=a0R11000002wRa9
```

I uploaded a template to the Adobe Dashboard, with text tags. I then made a merge mapping with 'Service Contract (reference)' as a basis, and then different data.

For the `'Map Data into Agreement Fields'` I chose `'Select Master Object Field'` as Mapping Method, and set `'Select Source Field from Master Object'` to `'Service Contract ID (ID)'`, and `'Target Agreement Field'` to `'Service Contract (reference)'`.

What am I doing wrong, and which setting did I not configure correctly? I don't do anything with Apex code except for the button. Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest you also contact the app vendor's support service as they are in the best position to help you with this.

Comment: Clearly the `echosign_dev1__SIGN_Agreement__c.echosign_dev1__Account__r` field is missing from the query they generated for you in their app. As @KeithC said, Adobe will need to help you sort out how to solve the issue.